# Two disjoint connected and bounded open sets in the plane that shares the same boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ with std. topology I want to exhibit two open sets that are connected, bounded and disjoint but that have a common boundary.

My attempt: 
Since both my sets need to be bounded, my thought was to limit them by the unitary ball. Its easy to construct two disjoint open sets that have a common boundary in the interior of the unitary circle, the problem is, of course, the exterior (the boundary of the union). So I considered two closed paths, helix-like curves that in polar coordinates can be expressed by

$\gamma(t) = (1-e^{-t},t)$

$\gamma_2(t) = (1-e^{-0.5t},t)$

So, set $U$ consists of the points between the two curves, that is,
$U = \{(\rho, \theta) : 1-e^{-0.5\theta}<\rho<1-e^{-\theta}\}$ and $V = B_1(0)\setminus \overline{U}$. It's easy to show that $U$ is open, bounded and since it's path-connected it is connected. Same goes to $V$ and I guess $\partial U = \partial V = Im(\gamma)\cup Im(\gamma_2) \cup D_1$ ($D_1$ being the unitary disk).

My questions: Is there an easier construction? Is my construction right?

Comment: Your construction is correct. For more interesting examples, google "lakes of wada".

Comment: @studiosus do you know an easier construction? Also, lakes of wada construction works for n>2 sets, isn't it?

Comment: Jonas: it works for any number of sets. The spiral construction is the easiest one I know.

Comment: It seems that $D_1$ should be the *boundary* of the unitary disk.

Comment: @AlexRavsky. In other words: the unit circle.